# Continuity of partial derivative

Tags: analysis, continuity, partial-derivative

I come up with this question while working on an exercise.

Suppose that $f(x,y)$ is defined in some neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$, $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}$ exists and is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$, $\partial f/\partial x$ exists. Is it true that $\partial f/\partial x$ is also continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$?  I think of Leibniz rule but its hypothesis include continuity in a neighborhood and not just at a point.

I appreciate any help.